# Overlap outlines in css

Tags: css

I have an HTML structure with many `divs` next to each other or below each other that all have an outline. The problem is, these outlines do not overlap, but are shown next to each other (or on top of each other). To illustrate, this is what happens: [image: css outlines next to each other]

This is my code, with added `nth-child()` selectors to clearly show the issue:

```css
.wrapper {
  /*  getting rid of the 'inline-block whitespace' */
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
}

.cell:nth-child(even) {
    outline: 6px solid blue;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) {
    outline: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      three
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My question is:** How to make these outlines overlap so no 'doubles' are shown?

**Update:** using half the margin of the width of the outline on the cells does not always work when the outline width is `1px`. For example, when the `padding` of `.cell` is `4px` this is the result (when you zoom in you will see the two lines).

**Update2:** it seems this is a bug with Firefox on a 4k display. Running this in Firefox on a display with a HD resolution or in another browser (tested Chrome) works.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply a margin equal to half the outline:

```css
.wrapper {
  /*  getting rid of the 'inline-block whitespace' */
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 3px; /* added */
}

.cell:nth-child(even) {
  outline: 6px solid blue;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) {
  outline: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      three
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use margin on one side:

```css
.wrapper {
  /*  getting rid of the 'inline-block whitespace' */
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0 6px 6px 0; /* added */
}

.cell:nth-child(even) {
  outline: 6px solid blue;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) {
  outline: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="cell">
      three
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not always work with an outline of 1px. I have added an example to the original question.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber which is logical since you need to deal with less than 1px and all the rounding issue with it (especially if you are zooming)

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and still had the issue (in Firefox). I then tried it in Chrome and it works. Also your first suggestion works in Chrome. (no zooming issues either, which there should not be because even though the size of the margin is smaller than 1px, the outline itself is not). So now I am guessing this is an issue with Firefox...

Comment: I tried it on a different machine with a HD-display instead of a 4k display. In this case it works in FF as well as other browsers, so my guess now is it is a bug with FF op 4k. Either way, your suggestion works!